# Using webpack aliases in vue components

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component

How do I use webpack aliases in Vue components?

For instance, setting an image url when the component is displayed:

```
<template>
  <img src="~@/assets/placeholder.jpg" ref="image"> <!-- this image works -->
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
     const which = '1';  // this would presumably be dynamic
     this.$refs.image.src = `~@/assets/${which}-image.jpg`;  // doesn't work
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Hm have you tried with `this.$nextTick` ? `const which = '1'
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.$refs.image.src = `~@/assets/${which}-image.jpg`;
});`

Comment: It's not the setting of the image that doesn't work, it's that the `~@` isn't resolved to the assets folder, it's used in the `src` literally and the image isn't packed.

Comment: I'd love to see this answered, I don't know of a way that you can do this currently.

Comment: try `this.$refs.image.src = require(\`~@/assets/${which}-image.jpg\`);  // doesn't work`. Note that since this is a dynamic require, everything in the assets folder will be bundled at compile time.

Comment: @EricGuan I imagine that would work, but `require` wants string literals in the AirBnB eslint config.  Is this the only way to do it?

Comment: I imagine it wants string literals b/c of the "bundling everything" problem. If you think that bundling everything in `assets` is acceptable, i would just disable the eslint rule here. By nature webpack does its thing at the build step, so it can't magically know which assets to bundle if you use a dynamic require. I'm not an webpack expert so don't quote me on that. You can add regex filters to a dynamic require, check out the docs.

Comment: @EricGuan If you want to add an answer, I will mark it as the correct one